# jquery ajax post and forget and redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this a tag that has a `useractivity` that is linked up to this on click function. The on click function has the `e.preventDefault();` so I need to do the rediect in this function but I want to do post and forget and redirect using the href link? what is the best way to do this?

HTML

```
<p class="anchorButton">
  <a class="useractivity" href="/information-and-materials">I Agree</a>
</p>
```

JS

```
$('.useractivity').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveUserActivitylog", "NCCNUserActivity")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            ResourceURL: window.location.pathname,
            Tag: $(this).text()
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: *"I want to do post and forget and redirect using the href link"* - can you explain what that means?

Comment: My guess: You want to POST to the `SaveUserActivitylog` action and *then* (on success) redirect to `/information-and-materials`?

Comment: that correct I dont need to wait for the return

Comment: well... that's easy. set `window.location.href = this.href;` after the Ajax call

Comment: But would that need to go in both `success` and `error` , I want to do it  no matter what the result it?

Comment: No, neither. Put it on on line *after* the Ajax call.